# Xcode wont allow 2 projects on my phone at a time.?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I've been working on a few apps and now when I run them on my iPhone, Xcode will only let one app be on my phone at a time, and if I load up another app in xcode, and try to run it, it kind of over writes the first app instead of haveing two apps on.

Have I done something wrong or is this the new Xcode and iOS6 to stop piracy?

Comment: Strange. What version of Xcode are you using? I'm using version 4.6.2 and am able to load multiple projects onto my iPhone. The only thing that I can think that would possibly cause it to overwrite your app for a different project is if the bundle identifiers for both projects are the same. You can check this under the Summary tab with your main application target selected.

Answer (score 4):

No, the apps probably have the same bundle identifier.  I'd check your project settings to make sure each app has a unique bundle identifier.

Comment: You might also try making one icon red and the other blue - just to check.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i thought u need to have the same bundle identifier for it to run on your device.?

Comment: Same one for the app each time you deploy that one app, but not the same one for every app.